# re mount component and change its state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I have an app where users can see a list of events, the events are split up into different categories i.e music, art etc.
What Im trying to do is that if a user clicks on a category where there are no events in that category yet, the user will be able to click a button that will bring them, to the "All Events" category list.
Im using a component called EventListScreen, which is im using as template for all the category lists, so instead of having a screen for each category, I just use the EventListScreen as the main Screen to list the events.

My problem is that if Im on the Art category and there are no events there I want the user to click a button that will bring them straight to the All Events Category, but when I try do 
`this.props.navigation.navigate("EventListScreen",{category: "All Events"})`

nothing happens as Im already on the EventListScreen.

I have read in places that some people say to just remount the component, but Im not sure how to do that as well as change the category to `All Events`

I have added the all events button code below:

```
<Text style={{paddingTop: 40, fontSize: 20}}>
        Sorry no events in here yet.
      </Text>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          this.props.navigation.navigate("EventListScreen", {
            category: "All Events"
          });
        }}>
        <Text style={{paddingTop: 20, fontSize: 15}}>
          Click here to see All Events
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Try add key to navigate function 
key: Math.random ()  * 10000

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Im not quite sure what you mean. would you be able to show me an example please

Comment: How do you receive data sent to EventListScreen?

Comment: @hongdevelop Hi, The event list screen receives Data from 2 places. 1 the user will have come from the categories screen, so if they clicked on the art category, "Art" will be passed through as a param, to the eventListScreen, then events will be fetched from firebase with the category Art. if the user clicks on the All Events category then they will be brought the eventListScreen again but will be shown all the events stored in firebase.

Comment: just add key into navigate function in the end (navigation.navigate({ routeName, params, action, key }) )